# What is the relation of weak digestion on weight gain/loss?

Tags: weight-loss

I was talking to someone about weight loss recently and jokingly they mentioned that they should just take diuretics so the food they eat won't be able to be processed and therefore not all the calories will count. We are both aware this is a bad idea and was merely a joke, but this brings me to my question, do people who have a poor ability to digest nutrients have a harder time gaining weight? Since the equation is basically how many calories in vs how many go out determines your weight gain/loss, in theory if not enough calories are able to be processed, wouldn't this be like adding fewer calories up front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: This answer talks a lot about bodily fluids because it references malabsorption and the side-effects of malabsorption.

Yes. An extreme example of what you're referring to is called [Malabsorption](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/malabsorption#:%7E:text=Malabsorption%20is%20difficulty%20in%20the,Chronic%20pancreatitis). It is a condition in which the body has difficulty digesting certain nutrients, and is caused by certain ailments such as celiac disease or lactose intolerance. Depending on the type and severity, the common side effect is [trouble gaining/keeping weight, diarrhea, and/or thick stools](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/malabsorption-syndrome#:%7E:text=Malabsorption%20causes%20abdominal%20discomfort%2C%20including%20gas%20and%20bloating.%20Other%20symptoms%20you%20may%20have%3A) because the food isn't being digested, and so it just passes through.

You don't need to look at troubled digestion to see similar affects. [Fiber, for example, does not entirely get digested](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/fiber/art-20043983#:%7E:text=Unlike%20other%20food%20components%2C%20such,and%20out%20of%20your%20body.). If you live in the U.S, you might notice the FDA allows companies to remove fiber from calorie calculations*. You would experience symptoms similar to what is described above if you were to over-supplement fiber.

It's also the mechanism of how artificial sweeteners like [erythritol](https://www.webmd.com/diet/what-is-erythritol) work. The body can't digest it entirely so it passes right through. Hence why they are "zero-calories". Overconsumption can cause similar symptoms as stated above as well as a sweet smelling urine.

*If you are counting calories, [soluble fiber has about 2 calories per gram](https://mccord.cm.utexas.edu/chembook/page.php?chnum=9&sect=6#:%7E:text=Soluble%20Fiber%20%2D%20this%20special%20type%20of%20fiber%20does%20ultimately%20provide%20about%202%20kcal/g.%20So%20if%20you%20see%20some%20soluble%20fiber%20listed%20on%20the%20nutrition%20label%2C%20you%20will%20get%20a%20little%20energy%20off%20of%20it.%20But%20as%20a%20reminder%20here%2C%20insoluble%20fiber%20provides%20zero%20calories.%20Only%20soluble%20fiber%20gives%20you%20the%202.). It's very difficult to determine how much of your daily fiber was soluble vs insoluble based on nutrition labels alone. Ultimately it won't make too much of a difference but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Wow, I learned much more than I expected to from this! I had no idea the FDA allows companies to remove fiber from calorie calculations or why artificial sweeteners were listed as 0 calories. Thanks!